# Pinning vertex on soft body to mesh not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, soft-body

I am trying to get a rope to follow a spearhead and flex as the spearhead moves. I can't seem to attach the two. Any help please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another user asked (approx. at the same time as you) kinda the same thing, in as to how to only have certain parts of your mesh be affected by the softbody-sim: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173592/how-to-apply-a-soft-body-simulator-on-a-certain-part-of-an-object/173892#173892 
You can use my answer from this question as it should work here as well; i.e. set the goal default value to 1 and in your pinning-Vertexgroup give the vertices that should be connected to the head a value of 1 as well. I think ropes aren't actually "soft" tho, you might use cloth sims instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hook modifier to your rope (use CTRL-H from edit mode, having selected your pinning vertex, to hook this up to an empty), and parent the resulting empty to your javelin.

Comment: Great, I appreciate the help